# Beaver Builder, how can I align buttons in a advanced post module?

Tags: button, vertical-alignment

How can I align the buttons in a UABB advanced posts module, as shown below.
Using css Flex breaks the lay-out.
Wondering if it's possible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LiFg.png)

Tried to use:
{ display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: flex-end;flex: 1 1 0; }
On the button, but that does'nt work.